# Auto sorting records in spreadsheet as soon as value is entered

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to auto sort values in Google Sheets as soon as I enter value in a cell. Below is an example:

```
| S. No. | Task   | Value |
| 1      | Task 1 | $$    |
| 2      | Task 2 | $$$   |
| 3      | Task 3 | $$$$  |
|        |        |       |
```

In the above table, as soon as I enter Value field for Task 3, I want it to go to top and the first one should come to the end. I don't want to achieve this manually by sorting every time.

Comment: Look at the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event macro. Write some code. Come back and show the code if you run into problems.

Comment: btw, is this [Excel] or [google-spreadsheet]? They are two completely different things when speaking about automated code. Pick one and own it. Don't throw mud at a wall to see what sticks.

Comment: on a google sheet, you could try the SORT formula to create a sorted copy of your table which would update automatically as new values are entered

Comment: Please don't tag Google sheets questions with the Excel tag.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Chris Hick's suggestion, you might enter your data in any order and have a copy sorted to suit. Since your example appears well ordered (ascending) I have assumed you would like it ordered descending (by `S. No.`) and that that is in A1:

```
=query(A:C,"Select * where A is not NULL order by A desc")
```

Add a couple of entries`9` in A5, `8` in A6 and the resulting list will be ordered 9,8,3,2,1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script to automatically sort your table. To do this, go to tools > script editor. This will open a new window.

Delete the code that you see and paste the below in:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cellColumn = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
  var currentSheet = sh.getName();
  if ((cellColumn == 3) && currentSheet == "enter sheet name here") { 
    var range = sh.getRange("A2:C");
    range.sort({column:2, ascending:false});
  }
}
```

You will need to change the "enter sheet name here" to the name of the sheet that you want to be sorted. Make sure to leave the quote marks in.

If you want to change the sort so that it is ascending, change the last line from

```
ascending:false
```

to

```
ascending:true
```

If you want to change the range of the data that is sorted, then you can do that on the row above. At the moment it is set to sort the range `A2:C`.